# XAML Sometimes icon is not displayed in list view cell

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, binding

I am trying to display a text + an image in a list view cell using a DataTemplate.

```
<ListView 
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
        Name="PlaybackListView" 
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Playbacks}"
        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">

     <ListView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="StatusCellTemplate">
           <WrapPanel>
              <TextBlock Name="StatusTextBlock" Width="Auto" Text="{Binding Status}" />
              <Image Source="{Binding Converter={StaticResource PlaybackViewItemToStatusImageSource}}" Height="14" Width="14" />
           </WrapPanel>        
        </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.Resources>

     <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
           <! -- Columns -->
           <GridViewColumn 
              Header="Status" 
              Width="130"
              CellTemplate="{StaticResource StatusCellTemplate}" />
           <! -- Columns -->
        </GridView>
     </ListView.View>
```

The problem is that sometimes the icon is shown but sometimes it isnt. Even if the same source path is used.

This is the convert method of the ValueConverter i use in the binding:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
     object result = value;

     PlaybackViewItem item = value as PlaybackViewItem;
     if (item != null)
     {
        switch (item.Status)
        {
           case PlaybackStatus.FilePreparationFinished:
           case PlaybackStatus.RadioPreparationFinished:
           case PlaybackStatus.Started:
              result = Path.Combine(IconsPath, "SignCheck.png");
              break;
           case PlaybackStatus.Finished:
              // HasPlaybackErrors is always false
              result = Path.Combine(IconsPath, !item.HasPlaybackErrors ? "SignCheck.png" : "WarningYellow.png");
              break;
           case PlaybackStatus.RadioPreparationFailed:
           case PlaybackStatus.FilePreparatinoFailed:
           case PlaybackStatus.CannotBeStarted:
           case PlaybackStatus.Failed:
           case PlaybackStatus.Stopped:
              result = Path.Combine(IconsPath, "SignExclamation.png");
              break;
           default:
              result = null;
              break;
        }
     }
     else
     {
        result = null;
     }

     return result;
  }
```

[image: Here u see that the image is not showing]

In the picture above you can see that in one case it isnt showing an image even if it has the same status.

There are also no binding errors or anything in the debug output.

Comment: It doesn't have to be the same path. If `HasPlaybackErrors == true` then _WarningYellow.png_ will be used. Do you have this file?

Comment: yes all files are present and HasPlaybackErrors is hardcoded to false

Comment: Is `Finished` its initial value? Your icon won't be automatically refreshed when `Status` will change. You can check with [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) what is the current value of `Source` on the `Image`

Comment: Ok i found the problem, its in the Binding of the Image.
I bind directly to the ViewItem I use and this only "changes" once when its added to the list. Therefor my value converter is only called with the intial state.
I would need to bind to the "Status" property of my view item but still get the whole ViewItem in my converter so i can check the "HasPlaybackErrors" property.

Comment: use [`IMultiValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `IValueConverter` with `MultiBinding`

Comment: Is `PlaybackViewItemToStatusImageSource` now `IMultiValueConverter`? Also second binding can now be `<Binding Path="HasPlaybackErrors" />`

Comment: binding is working, now i am trying to return a valid ImageSource

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told us where your images are, but if they are in a folder named `Images` in your project root folder, then you can simply reference them in your `Converter` like this:

```
result = "/AppName;component/Images/ImageName.png";
```